# Output changing electrical currents from a PC

Tags: usb, current, computers

I need to send fast-changing electrical current from a computer to electrodes connected to muscle (Not the point).

I need to send multiple different currents simultaneously, and that the current could be changed on command from the PC.

I don't need something like an Arduino, I need the component IN the Arduino that allows this.

The main problem is that I need the change to be fast, less then a second.

I don't know many of the technical terms so I might have missed a similar question.

Comment: This is a potentially dangerous project, make sure you are well aware of risks involved and how to mitigate them.

Comment: I'd be more concerned that you don't know the technical terms required to know if what you are doing is safe or not. It takes remarkably little current in the right spot to stop a heart. But even that small current requires a fairly high voltage to achieve, which also creates safety issues for your embedded system, the attached PC, and potentially its user.

Answer (score 2):

Use a microcontroller to control a current source or sink, and have that communicate to the PC.  UART communication will be easiest at the micro.  If your PC doesn't have a serial port, you can use a USB to serial adapter.  This doesn't sound like a product, so that is probably good enough.

The micro can easily respond to commands from the PC and change the output of a current sink or source in well under a second.  That is actually quite a lon time.

Comment: Thank you. But, I need to be sure that there wouldn't be any unneccessary components.

Comment: In neurostimulators there are no unneccessary components. I have a neurotron unit in the other room -- it is a large suitcase sized machine.

Comment: Mr. Lathrop's answer is correct. On the hardware side, you will need a high voltage (~100) DC source and a constant current driver to account for different electrode-skin contact resistances.

Answer (score 1):

Noting the 1st two comments under your question, and advising you to heed them, I would use the sound card output and a suitable analogue buffer/amplifier circuit if required.

Most PC's have 5.1 or 7.1 outputs these days, which is plenty of channels.

HOWEVER, you really MUST understand a LOT more about what you're doing before you start electrocuting yourself or anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (If you have it) the parallel port directly to a DAC (digital to analog convertor), and you can access to the parallel port using the port address.

The only problem is that the ports are blocked by windows, so you have to download a special program to unlock it.

Note: the parallel port is not protectec against shortcuts, so be carefull you don't damage the board.

Hope I could help you.